# C++ XOR Function

Tags: c++, performance, converting

This XOR function is costing my program too much time (specifically the conversions.)

**How can this code be made faster?**

---

```
string xor_str(string astr, string bstr){
    unsigned long a = strtoul(astr.c_str(), NULL, 16);  // Convert strings to longs
    unsigned long b = strtoul(bstr.c_str(), NULL, 16);

    stringstream sstream;
    sstream << setfill('0') << setw(16) << hex << (a ^ b);  // XOR numbers and
    string result = sstream.str();  // Save result          // convert to string
    sstream.clear();  // Clear buffer (will this happen anyway?)
    return result;
}
```

For example, `xor_str("74657374696e6731", "1111111111111111")` returns `"65746265787f7620"`.

Comment: Speed comparison: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/RL0Jq.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RL0Jq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing the xor on patched ASCII values instead, I'm sort of in doubt about performance of general purpose `strtoul`.

I didn't profile it, so I may be underestimating the optimizations of modern compilers. Anybody will profile it, just for curiosity? :)

edit:
The OP code will work even for input strings with different lengths (i.e. `("1234", "4")` will produce `0000000000001230`. My code will work only with already leading-zero extended numbers of same length, although the length can be arbitrary, not just 16.

```
std::string xor_str(const std::string& astr, const std::string& bstr)
{
    const size_t bsize = bstr.size();
    assert(astr.size() == bsize);
    // this xor_str will work over arbitrary long strings, they just have to have same size
    string result(bsize, 0);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bsize; ++i) {
        // astr[i] and bstr[i] is something from '0'..'9', 'a'..'f' or 'A'..'F'
        char ra = astr[i], rb = bstr[i];
        // make lower nibble of chars 0..F, from ASCII 'a'+9 = 0x6A, 'A'+9 = 0x4A
        if ('9' < ra) ra += 9;
        if ('9' < rb) rb += 9;
        ra = (ra^rb)&0x0F;  // xor lower nibbles of chars
        // transfer 'ra' back to ASCII and store it to result
        if (ra <= 9) result[i] = ra + '0';
        else         result[i] = ra + 'a' - 10; // or 'A' for uppercase output
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I profiled both this and Quuxplusone's code, and this is almost twice as fast.

Comment: @54696D: in case you want to use as input non-leading-zero extended strings of different length, it's sort of easy to extend this code to handle it with fake '0' prologue. Also maybe using `char buffer[]` instead of `string result`, and let the `return` create instance of string from buffer may save you one clearing of memory (as there's no way to allocate result string with uninitialized memory, so the `result(bsize, 0)` is maybe wasting some small amount of time - but I have no idea how long the instance of string from buffer takes). How about not using `string` at all? (vector or array?)

Comment: @54696D: oh, now I have seen the profiling results, and indeed, the `string` itself is taking some measurable time. If you really want to have full performance for this, consider managing the memory on your own (vector/char[] with reserved sizes), string is a bit high level. And I have suspicion my routine can be written with SSE/AVX instructions in mind working on packed bytes, which would probably make it about 8-16 times faster. But I would have to study some materials for couple of hours before producing the source for that (not even sure how to do that in C++, some compiler intrinsics?).

Comment: I'm not planning on using intrinsic instructions, but I did swap all the strings with char arrays, and it's 25% faster.

Answer (score 6):

Well, obviously you should get rid of all that stringstream stuff in favor of the straightforward

```
char buffer[100];
sprintf(buffer, "%016x", a ^ b);
return buffer;
```

That'll cut out all those virtual function calls and stateful stream operations in favor of just doing what you want: print a single integer in hex.

---

Also, you may not have noticed, but you're taking the parameters `astr` and `bstr` by *value* instead of by const reference, so depending on how you're calling this function, you might be spending most of your time making copies of `std::string` objects, not hexifying them *per se*. My guess is that this is actually a bigger time sink than the stringstream stuff, even though that's what caught my eye first.

---

Therefore I'd try benchmarking

```
std::string xor_str(const std::string& astr, const std::string& bstr)
{
    unsigned long a = strtoul(astr.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    unsigned long b = strtoul(bstr.c_str(), NULL, 16);
    char buffer[100];  // "big enough"
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%016lx", a ^ b);
    return buffer;
}
```

(Notice that you could use `sprintf` instead, since in this particular case you know there can't be any overflow — and you *are* concerned about raw speed. But my assumption is that you aren't very good at profiling to find hotspots, and *are* looking for style tips in general, so the general advice "Always use `snprintf` over `sprintf`" wins out over the very case-specific and chainsawish "Omit bounds checks when you're *sure* they're unnecessary.")

Comment: Since xor won't go out of bounds, couldn't the buffer just be 16 chars long?  `char buffer[16];`

Comment: Well, `17`, because of the trailing null terminator... but yes, my `100` was just me being too lazy to figure out the exact maximum required size (which in this particular case is super easy to figure out, because we say "`016lx`" right in the code, but I was too lazy to even notice *that*). `char buffer[17];` would be fine.